# Issue a constant attribute in a claim

Tags: saml, adfs2.0, adfs

We have a rule to issue an attribute to one of our Relying Third Parties that matches the following exactly (obviously I've made some changes):

```
<Attribute Name="http://example.com/#Something" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
    <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">http://example.com</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
```

I don't see anything in the [Claim Rule language](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd807118%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that would allow me to make the above - getting the `Attribute Name` part is easy, and getting the value of the `AttributeValue` is easy, but adding `NameFormat` and getting the type of `AttributeValue` doesn't seem to be coming along.

For example, this:

```
=> issue(Type = "http://example.com/#Something",
         Value = "http://example.com",
         ValueType = "string");
```

Can get us to here:

```
<Attribute Name="http://example.com/#Something">
    <AttributeValue a:type="tn:string" xmlns:tn=" http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">http://something.com</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
```

We've also tried `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string` for `ValueType` with fairly similar results.  I don't see anything that can add the `NameFormat`, and there's definitely a lot more information being added to the `AttributeValue` than we require.

Is there a way to just issue a constant claim?  There is nothing variable about the values; I would love to just be able to drop the XML somewhere and have it integrate into the overall SAML message.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but hope it helps others.

Does the below example help?

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"] 
=> issue( 
Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", 
Issuer = c.Issuer, 
OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, 
Value = c.Value, 
ValueType = c.ValueType, 
Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/attributename"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri");
```

The key part is manipulating properties with the NameFormat identified by URI http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/attributename . http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2010/06/21/a-quick-walkthrough-setting-up-ad-fs-saml-federation-with-a-shibboleth-sp.aspx has more details on nameformat.

You can skip condition check and just issue claims as follows

```
=> issue( 
    Type = "http://example.com/#Something", 
    Value = "http://example.com", 
    Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/attributename"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified");
```

Comment: Works great :-)   Also, if you need to send multiple constants, they are sent in separate claims rules.